# can ItemProcessor write to two different files?

Tags: spring-batch

I have an item processor that get FieldSet count of a line/record, if it equals 5 then it writes the record to a file via the FlatFileItemWriter (say goodRecords.csv).  But i also want to write the records that do NOT equal 5 to another file (say badRecords.csv).  Is it possible to use one ItemProcessor for this task?

Here is my code of the ItemProcessor:

```
    @Override
public FieldSet process(FieldSet line) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x = line.getFieldCount();
    if(x==5){
        return line;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an ItemProcessor issue, it's an ItemWriter issue (ItemProcessors are for updating and filtering).  Check out the ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.  It will allow you to inject a Classifier that returns the appropriate ItemWriter to write to.  You can read more about it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html